# Обработка пустой строки в консоли в Java

Tags: java, scanner

Пишу кодер и декодер шифра Цезаря.  Не могу найти информацию, как сделать так, чтобы человек, оставляя строчку пустой, просто нажимал <kbd>Enter</kbd>, и тогда создавался бы файл с определенным именем.
У меня консоль всегда требует ввода хоть чего-нибудь.

> ```
> System.out.println("Введите ссылку на файл или имя файла, в который вы хотите записать зашифрованный текст");
> String linkOut = input.next();
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `Scanner::next` игнорирует разделители и считывает непустой токен *ДО первого разделителя*, по умолчанию к разделителям относятся все пробельные символы, для которых [`Character::isWhitespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)) возвращает `true`, включая и перевод строки `\n`.

```java
String nonEmptyString = input.next(); // ждёт непустого ввода без пробелов
System.out.println("'" + nonEmptyString + "'");
```

Если нужно разрешить ввод пустой строки, достаточно использовать метод [`Scanner::nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), который читает всю строку целиком, НЕ включая сам символ перевода строки в конце.
Такая строка может быть пустой или содержать только пробельные символы (разделители) за исключением перевода строки (см. [System.lineSeparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator())).

```java
System.out.println("Введите название файла или нажмите `Enter`, для названия по умолчанию myfile.txt");
String filename = input.nextLine().trim(); // ждёт ввода строки
System.out.println("'" + filename + "'");
if (filename.isEmpty()) {
    filename = "myfile.txt";
}
```